# How to concatenate with a leading zero in number less than 10

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have an hour and a minute column in my dataset. I want to concatenate them so that there is a "." in between. In cases where the minute column is less than 10, I want to add a leading zero.

Example of what I want it to look like:

Hour(A): 1
Minute (B): 2
Desired Outcome (C): 1.02

I have been playing with this formula Con (A,”.”, IF (Len (B) =1, con (0, B), B)) but I can't seem to make it work

Can anyone give any insight?

Comment: do you mean con("0",B) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=A1&"."&TEXT(B1,"00")
```

Or this also works:

```
=TEXT(TIME(A1,B1,0),"h.mm")
```

---

As required:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in column C,

```
=time(a1, b1, 0).
```

Format the cell as `h.mm`.

[image]